# How to Fix Unity IOS Facebook Error on App Launch

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am integrating Facebook Login & Sharing into a game for IOS using Unity. But as soon as app launches i am getting this error

```
-> applicationWillResignActive()
2019-03-11 16:39:07.405809+0500[828:197716] +[NSError fbErrorWithCode:userInfo:message:underlyingError:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1d2710f80



2019-03-11 16:39:07.466234+0500 [828:197716] Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: +[NSError fbErrorWithCode:userInfo:message:underlyingError:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1d2710f80
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [tour], [ask], [mcve] to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got almost same error codes in my project on Swift. So is not problem Unity, is problem connection Facebook SDK to project.

In my case, this error happened, when I try use VPN application Luna. Is seem have conflict VPN with Facebook SDK if is connected to project not correct. When VPN disabled, application and analytics worked without any problem.

For fix my problem, in "**Project->Build Settings**" need have parameter "**Other Linker Flags**" value "**-ObjC**".

Also I used **bridge** "**.h**" file for connect Facebook SDK to my Swift project. I had line "`#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>`", so I delete it from bridge. And manual added in every Swift class, what used Facebook SDK this line:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the "**FBSDKCoreKit**" parameter in "**Other Linked Flags**". Adding the package, then cleaning the build was a fix for me